# bootstrap Menu bar should be in expandable vertically from left to right

Tags: php, menubar

i have bootstrap menu bar suppose this link https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar-top/.  I need menu like the this link  https://lekmer.se/  when it is  mobile view . please help me in this task. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can expand it from left to right just change .navbar-nav css 
`-webkit-box-orient: vertical;` to
`-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;` and 
`flex-direction: column;` to `flex-direction: row;`
in all sections of CSS. Sample code as below

```
.navbar-nav {
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    list-style: none
}
```